# JavaScript console logs not synchronized to DOM/JavaScript execution

Tags: javascript, console.log

I have the following code which looks for links with an href attribute which start with "http" and saves them to **extLinks**, and then prints them out:

```
var extLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="http"]')

for (let i=0; i<extLinks.length; ++i) {
    console.log(extLinks[i]);
}
```

Then I add a delay of 100ms before adding a target attribute with a value of "_blank" to each item in **extLinks**:

```
console.log("again");
var x = setTimeout(printLater, 10);

function printLater() {
    for (let i=0; i<extLinks.length; ++i) {
        console.log(extLinks[i]);
        if (!extLinks[i].hasAttribute("target")) {
            extLinks[i].setAttribute("target", "_blank");
        }
    }
}
```

If the delay is 100ms, the print out is (**in Chrome**):
*(Notice the first set of prints don't have a target attribute set)*
[image: First print out has no target, second has]

However if the delay is 10ms, the print out is:
*(Notice the first set of prints has the target attribute set even though the code to add it has not reached execution yet)*
[image: both print outs have target set, second has]

My question is, should one not trust prints outs to accurately reflect the state of the DOM? It appears it can change the DOM faster than it can console.log the state of it? Is that the reason for the above behavior?

Comment: Hi @run_the_race, does my answer solver your question? If it does, could you please mark it as accepted it? If if doesn't could you please let me know why? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Josep, I have read your answer about 5 times, and its still unclear to me. I researched what mutation is. I tried the example that you said in the console, but I dont see how it relates to your explanation. I tried querying it a completely different variable (to avoid mutation), but it still behaved the same. i.e. var extLinks2 = <the same query>. Still trying to understand it. I come back to it every so often, thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are mutating the instances and chrome is just displaying the instance in the console, if you want to log a "snapshot" of the instance you should clone it, like this:

```
var x = setTimeout(printLater, 10);

function printLater() {
    for (let i=0; i<extLinks.length; ++i) {
        console.log(extLinks[i].cloneNode());
        if (!extLinks[i].hasAttribute("target")) {
            extLinks[i].setAttribute("target", "_blank");
        }
    }
}
```

Try this experiment to better understand what's happening:

- Open the console in Chrome.
- Define the following variable inside the console: `const foo = {};`
- Now, log that variable: `console.log(foo);`
- Inspect the logged instance `foo` (open it), it's empty, right?
- Now, write this in the console: `foo.bar = 'bar';` and press enter.
- Inspect that instance again, what do you see? :-)